# Can't enable billing for a fresh Google Cloud Platform project in Python API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-api-client

The project was created by Python using the google_application_defaults, billing API was successfully activated and checked on command line with

```
os.system(gcloud services enable cloudbilling.googleapis.com)
os.system(gcloud services list --enabled)
```

Then, when running:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery, errors, logging
CB = discovery.build("cloudbilling", "v1", credentials = default_creds,  cache_discovery = False)   
billing_body = {"projectID": projectID, "name": "projects/"+projectID+"/billingInfo", "billingEnabled": True, "billingAccountName": "billingAccounts/"+billingAccount}
billingUP = CB.projects().updateBillingInfo(name = projectID, body = billing_body )
try:
    billing_resp = billingUP.execute()
    print("Billing succesfully enabled")
except errors.HttpError as err:
    billing_resp = None
    print("request voided")
    logging.error("There was an error creating the project. Check:")
    logging.error(err._get_reason())
```

I get the following error:

```
Cloud Billing API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXX before or it  is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudbilling.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

I also tried activating it directly on command line outside the python script but the error persist. I've tred using different formats in the "projectID" part on the billingUp request: projectName, projects/projectName, projectID, projects/projectID and nothing works. Any possible solutions?

Comment: Is it possible that billing was indeed enabled, but it just hasn't propagated yet?

Comment: Try this command: `gcloud beta billing accounts list` If this reports an API error, you have not enabled billing. If it works, then you have a code problem or you did not wait long enough for the API to be enabled.

Comment: @JohnHanley the command works with no problem, shows the accounts name, id and status.

Comment: @DustinIngram Uhm, I doubt it since it's two days i've been trying this.

Comment: Verify that the project account number matches the project for the service account credentials that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below code, these GCP docs are very unclear to understand and implement

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
projectID="<project id>"
biling_account_id = "<billing account id>"
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
from googleapiclient import discovery, errors, logging
CB = discovery.build("cloudbilling", "v1", credentials = credentials)   
 
billing_body = {
  "name": "projects/"+ projectID+"/billingInfo",
  "projectId": projectID,
  "billingEnabled": True,
  "billingAccountName": "billingAccounts/"+biling_account_id
}


print(billing_body)

billingUP = CB.projects().updateBillingInfo(name = "projects/"+ projectID,body=billing_body)
try:
    billing_resp = billingUP.execute()
    print("Billing succesfully enabled")
except errors.HttpError as err:
    billing_resp = None
    print("request voided")
    logging.error("There was an error enabling billing for the project. Check:")
    logging.error(err._get_reason())
```

Answer (score 1):

The error given in the response is informative enough. Before you use specific APIs or Services in GCP, you need to enable them first, using the console. In this example, the `Cloud Billing API` is not enabled. Go to the following URL. (This URL is also given in the response).

```
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudbilling.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Replace `XXXXXXXXXXX` with the Project ID. You will see an interface like below. Click on `ENABLE`.

[image]

Now we come to the second part of the error message. You actually need to wait for like 5 mins. The following error message actually asks you to do that.

```
If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

Now run your API query, and you will get a response.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a workaround, very primitive solution but worked. Hope there is another way to do it. All I did was calling a command shell with os.system and using gcloud to enable it:

```
 billing_command = "gcloud beta billing projects link {} --billing-account {}".format(projectID, billingAccount)
os.system(billing_command)
```